# Fixed height of the_content()

Tags: css, the-content, characters, limit

I have page with news. I'm displaying them as a shortened text (300 chars limit), I'm removing any images using preg_replace() and everything looks fine, until someone uses line breaks in his post. Things gets messy then and my height is way to high sometimes. Ofc I'm using `overflow: hidden;` but its not as good as I would like it to be. Is there a way to trim out those spaces, remove `<strong>` if someone uses it etc.? So my news page looks always as awesome as it should?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a [`wp_kses()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) on `the_excerpt()` (through a filter) you can whitelist specific HTML tags and such. In your case, the code would probably look something like this:

```
if( is_page( 'your_page' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse44363_filter_the_excerpt' );
}
function wpse44363_filter_the_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    // this allows no html, you can allow only links or something of that nature
    $allowed_html = array();
    return wp_kses( $excerpt, $allowed_html );
}
```

Comment: Useful function, thanks. So there is just one problem now. How can I change default `p`'s added to the content into `br`'s after user presses enter key? I know I can remove `p`'s by removing filter `wpautop`, but how to add `br`'s? Is this the right function to override?

Comment: You could probably do it with a string replace on `</p>` and a `preg_replace` on `<p>`, but I don't know why you would want to do that. You're much better off changing your CSS to do the line breaks and spacing. It's MUCH more flexible.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I don't know why I've tried to do such complex things when I can use just CSS. Anyway, thank You very much!